# Implmentation of org-id-goto but for arbitrary properties?

Tags: org-mode

Does there exist a function similar to `org-id-goto`, but instead one that can allow you to jump to tasks that have arbitrary property names (other than just "ID")? So for example `(org-goto "ID1" "VALUE")` would jump to the (perhaps first found) task with property `ID1` and value `VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

This jumps to the first heading with property `ID1` set to `VALUE` in the current buffer:

```lisp
(goto-char (org-with-wide-buffer (org-find-property "ID1" "VALUE")))
```

Found that function from looking at the source of `org-find-entry-with-id`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want C-c a m     (org-tags-view)

After you type C-c am, enter this at the prompt in the minibuffer:

```
ID1="VALUE"
```

you should get an agenda list of tasks matching that. You can open which ever one you want.